# flutter: one String Text with multiple colors inside the AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I would like to write the company name with the original colors inside the AppBar of the application.
For example the word "WhiteRed" with the "White" text in white color and "Red" text in red color.
At the moment I am using this method to do it inside the home page but I am not able to reproduce it inside the AppBar.

There is a method for it?

Thanks for your answer

```
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200, top: 200),
          child: Container(
            child: RichText(
              text: const TextSpan(
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                      text: 'White',
                      style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: 'Red',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Just use the same `RichText` in the `title` property of `AppBar`, it will work. Also consider using [Text.rich](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Text Widget inside a Row :

```
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Row(children: [
    Text('White', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    Text('Red', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
  ])),
```

Comment: Thanks, easy, it works, as you understand I am a beginner. thanks for the patience

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `RichText`. Here is the code

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'White',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'Red',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200, top: 200),
                child: Container(
                  child: RichText(
                    text: const TextSpan(
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: 'White',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: 'Red',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```